# On iOS, how can I delay the opening part of the cameraIris Animation

Tags: ios, animation, camera

I am displaying the iris animation manually with:

```
- (void)playPictureTakenAnimation {
    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    animation.type = @"cameraIris";
    animation.duration = 0.8f;
    animation.timingFunction = UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut;
    irisAinmationView.opaque = 1.0f;
    [irisAinmationView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
}
```

I need to pause the animation until the photo is been taken and is processed, e.g:

1. the shutter closes (first half of the animation)
2. the photo is taken and processed (the animation is paused), and then
3. reopen the shutter (second half of the animation)

Comment: cameraIris is undocumented.  There's not much we can do...

Answer (score 1):

To control the start and end points, use:

```
animation.startProgress = 0.0; // start
animation.endProgress = 0.5; // halfway
```

And:

```
animation.startProgress = 0.5; // halfway
animation.endProgress = 1.0; // end
```

Along with:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag
```

To get control when the animation stops.